# Python For Loop Equivalence

Tags: python, while-loop

I am a newbie in Python and have a question about for loop equivalence. Why are the codes below not equivalent?

```
squares = ['orange', 'orange', 'purple', 'blue ', 'orange']
new_squares = []
i = 0
#square = squares[i]           
""""Because while loop is iterate only inside its block that's why it can not consider your upper syntax( square = squares[i] )""""
while (square[i]== "orange"):
    new_squares.append(square)
    i = i + 1
print(new_squares)
```

```
squares = ['orange', 'orange', 'purple', 'blue ', 'orange']
new_squares = []
i = 0
while(squares[i] == 'orange'):
    new_squares.append(squares[i])
    i = i + 1
print (new_squares)
```

Comment: Because you never update `square` in your first sample.

Comment: Endless loop. You never update `square` to something different from `orange`

Comment: Infinite loop that will never terminate

Comment: Thank you people :)